# Double value into TextView

Tags: java, android, textview, double

I am trying to display time in 0.0 hours.  So I want to divide the minutes by 60 to get a .xx

This is what I have but I am not getting anything after the . even when there is an uneven number of minutes inputted...

```
double hoursLeftMins = hoursRemaining + (minsRemaining/60);
recommendTime.setText(Double.toString(hoursLeftMins));
```

Comment: What is the type of hoursRemaining and minsRemaining?

Answer (score 2):

if `minsRemaining` is `int` change the expression to

```
double hoursLeftMins = hoursRemaining + (minsRemaining/60.0);
```

Explanation: if you divide two integers, the decimal part will be truncated. In order to preserve the decimal part, you divide with `60.0`, so that the numbers are treated as real numbers, and not as integers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go more flexible, why not try TimeUnit?

```
long millis = ... //Total time in milliseconds
String time = String.format("%d min, %d sec", 
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis),
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis))
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest switching to BigDecimal, rather than double, for this arithmetic. In BigDecimal, it is easy to control both the number of digits after the decimal point and the rounding mode. Double.toString may give a lot more digits than you want.